# Installing facebook sdk for android, installation procedure, gen folder missing

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to use the facebook sdk for android, [available here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). I  have two questions:

**Problem 1:** From the instructions...
Step 1.Pull the repository from GitHub:
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git

Does this simply mean download the files?

**Problem 2:**
I downloaded the files and opened the samples as a New Android Project (from existing source).  The project files do not have anything in the gen folder.
I have tried

- Choosing Project >Build
- Choosing Project > Clean
- editing Java file (Example.java) and resaving it
- checking the Java commpliance level is 1.6 (Project > Properties > Java Compiler)
- deleting the gen folder and rebuilding (Project > Build)
- putting my Facebook App ID in the example.java file

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. cloning the repository means using the [Git version control system](http://git-scm.com/) to a local copy of the repository which you can update and get the latest code changes at any time. If you are not concerned with having the latest changes in the sdk then you can simply download the zip or tar file (which I think you did)
2. The contents of the gen folder are automatically generated when you build an android project. If there is an error in the build process then the gen folder maybe empty. Please check the console (Menu -> Window -> Show view -> Console" in Eclispe and see if there are any build errors.